# Swift How to use dismiss view controller properly/ How to make a back button with 3 View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

**Context**

I have 3 view controllers. A opens B that opens C. I have a back button in B and C. I want the back buttons to go from C -> B and from B -> A without reloading the view controller. I tried dismiss view controller.

**Problem**

if I go to B than C and dismiss C it goes back to B but then if I dismiss B it goes back to C, not to A

```
A -> B -> C -> back -> B -> back -> C

Should be: A -> B -> C -> back -> B -> back -> A
```

**Code**

in A, B and C:

```
@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
     dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController` to handle transitioning and lifecycle?

Comment: @toiavalle You should use popViewController in such situation.Controllers are added on top of each other in form of stack if you used UINavigationController .If you. Are trying to dismiss a controller then example( A-B-C) dismiss C it goes back and B comes on its top so it is still there below C.so you go back to C instead of A.

Comment: I would recommend using an unwind segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UINavigationController` and `push` the `UIViewControllers` instead of handling navigation by yourself. The `UINavigationController` will handle the correct behavior of the back button (no IBAction needed)

E.g. implement sth like this in your ViewController-A:

```
 @IBAction func showB() {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
 }
```

And Embed ViewController-A as `rootViewController` in an instance of `UINavigationController` in your storyboard or programmatically like this

```
let viewControllerA = ViewControllerA() // or instantiate from storyboard
let masterNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerA)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkHim. Should I use multiple VCs in the same NC or one NC for each VC? How can I connect multiple VCs to the same NC in StoryBoard?

Comment: @toiavalle connect with first controller.Then use segue for remaining .